# Fim das notificações vazias

Tags: novo-recurso, notificações

No stack,existem algumas notificações sem conteúdo,que apenas mostram o número 1 e nada mais.

Por que não avisar o que aconteceu,por exemplo:Uma notificação de "Uma pergunta de sua participação foi excluída"

Seria mais intuitivo do que apenas dar motivos para questionamentos desnecessários sobre o que aconteceu.

Comment: **Origem:** [Bugs de notificação](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1690/bugs-de-notifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Comment: Achei melhor criar uma pergunta direcionada a tal assunto.

Comment: Como assim? Quando você clica no idicador vermelho com o número 1, o site mostra os detalhes.

Comment: Algumas notificações não aparecem,por exemplo,hoje de manhã me deparei com uma notificação.Quando cliquei não apareceu nada de novo.Acontece várias vezes na verdade.3 pelo que lembro

Comment: @WeslleyCXSardinha Por um acaso você tinha mais de uma aba aberta? Se eu abro as abas A e B, ambas recebem uma notificação (digamos, um upvote: +10), e eu clico na notificação da aba A, aparece destacado do que se trata, e se eu clico na notificação ele me leva à página do perfil (i.e. tudo normal). Se depois eu volto pra aba B (pode ser horas depois, e eu nem me lembrar mais do ocorrido), a notificação ainda está lá, mas ao clicar nela não aparece nada destacado. Alguma chance disso ter ocorrido?

Comment: Pensando bem,pode sim ter acontecido isso.Vou prestar atenção caso ocorra novamente